# Dynamic Jquery Function with Rails - Compress multiple functions into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, function, show-hide

Right now I loop through my RoR objects and create a new jquery function for each separate object.  I understand this is extremely inefficient and amateurish, and I would like to have just one jquery function that handles this operation.

```
<% @startups.each do |startup| %>
  <div class="panel-body showVideo<%=startup.id%>">
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body theVideo<%=startup.id%>">
  ...
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('.theVideo<%=startup.id%>').hide();
      $('.showVideo<%=startup.id%>').on('click', function () {
        $('.theVideo<%=startup.id%>').show();
        $('.showVideo<%=startup.id%>').hide();
      });
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Basically this code waits for a user to click the div, and hides that div while showing another div.  The code currently works, but I don't want to create tons of functions when it could be one!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to give the JS access to your IDs. You could do that by writing them into your HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Write the IDs into the script tag
  var ids = [ <% @startups.each do |startup| %>
    <%=startup.id%>,
  <% end %>];
  // Loop over the IDs
  for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
    var id = ids[i];
    // Do your stuff here
  }
</script>
```

Of course add some logic to make sure not to add a comma to the last one.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I understand your concept, but I'm still not sure how to implement seeing as though I need to actually post the div's (One div that shows on page load, and one that shows when you click the first div)

Comment: What do you mean by "post the divs"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  What I mean is, I need to actually output the html.  Do I do that in the javascript or outside of the JS script?    Just not sure how to actually implement everything.

Comment: Well, you could certainly do it either way. If most of your app is in rails, I would just keep doing things that way and write out all the divs in rails.